# How to revert file but leave it in pending changelist?

Tags: perforce, p4v

In Perforce P4V I have a file in a pending changelist. I want to revert the contents of the file but keep the file in the changelist. How can I do that?

I tried Perforce's `revert` command but that removes the file from the changelist.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to accomplish this (short of copy/pasting the original contents back into this file, but that seems silly) is to revert and reopen it.  Shelving, by itself, does not revert the file. The concept of "shelve and revert" is still two operations.

Answer (score 4):

This is not readily possible, as other respondents noted.

If you are okay with a multi-step solution, you could

1. Right-click the file in the changelist and choose "diff against have revision".
2. In the diff window, under "Edit" choose "Edit right/left pane" (whichever side yours is
   on).
3. Copy the contents of the original and paste them over your edited workspace version
4. Save the file.

Your file now has no changes, and it is checked out in the same changelist.

Answer (score 3):

Using the command line, it can be done in three stages. If you are using windows I highly recommend having a unix environment, e.g. cygwin (which is the one I used.)

Assume your changelist number is XYZ and you have shelved the files in their current revision (just for the sake of it!)

Step 1: get a list of files and put them in a temp file.

```
p4 describe XYZ | grep \/\/ | sed -e 's/\.\.\. //'| sed 's/#.*//'  > temp
```

Step 2: revert all the files in the changelist

```
p4 revert -c XYZ //...
```

Step 3: check out / edit the files again

```
cat temp | xargs p4 edit -c XYZ
```

I assumed all the files are in edit mode (i.e. not an already opened file or a deleted file).

PS : delete temp, if you are fussy :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done, even from the command line, since `p4 sync` (even with `-f`) explicitly excludes operations on open files.

Answer (score -2):

The feature you're looking for is [shelving](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html). This will revert the file, but keep a shelved version in the changelist, which you (or someone else on a different client) can unshelve later.